# JS calculate position of events in timeline

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a small timeline / schedule in javascript but I'm hanging on one point. When I have multiple events on the same day or the same timespan the timeline should expand in height and the events should be displayed underneath each other. The events are all positioned absolute to the relative parent (row). What is the best way to detect if there is already an event at the same time / the position in the timeline?

So for the example below: How do event 6 and 8 know that they need to displayed underneath event 5 and how does event 7 knows that it is fine to be displayed at the top?

[image]

I thought about using "document.elementFromPoint(x, y)" to check if there is already an event at the desired position. Therefore I would have to check every day of the timespan of the event. That doesn't sound really performant to me.

Is there any other approach to deal with this problem? You guys have any other idea?

Comment: Every event has a start and end. Check if the start or end is between values of other events.

Comment: I thought about that too. In the schedule will be around 2000 events. Checking against each other could take a while. But the more important question for me is how do I know on what "line" the event is in case I found a matching event. 
So in the example: when I move event 7 one day to the left there will be 2 other events at the same time. How do I know I can still place it in the top line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So input is event list, output is grid with rows with events. Utility function: `is_overlap` between events. Then just do some loops until you find or allocate a place for each event, by order of apperance.

```js
var events = [
  {name: 'Event 5', start: 2, end: 6},
  {name: 'Event 6', start: 3, end: 9},
  {name: 'Event 7', start: 7, end: 12},
  {name: 'Event 8', start: 5, end: 11},
];

function is_overlap(eventA, eventB) {
  var x1 = eventA.start;
  var x2 = eventA.end;
  var y1 = eventB.start;
  var y2 = eventB.end;
  return (x1 <= y2 && y1 <= x2)
}

function get_timeline_rows(events) {
  var grid = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var event = events[i];

    var found_position = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < grid.length; j++) {
      var row = grid[j];
      var full = false;
      for (var slot = 0; slot < row.length; slot++) {
        var scheduled = row[slot];
        if (is_overlap(event, scheduled)) {
          full = true;
          break;
        }

      }
      if (!full) {
        row.push(event)
        found_position = true;
        break;
      }

    }
    if (!found_position) {
      var row = [event];
      grid.push(row)
    }

  }


  return grid;
}

console.log(get_timeline_rows(events))
```